# Implementing recursion into python3 class method

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, recursion

I need to use recursion in order for the input to keep calling itself if the sum of the two inputs don't equal to 100, but every time I try, I keep ending up with it asking for the input once, and then once it has been entered, it returns a hexadecimal value.

```
class Z:
    def __init__(self, probabilityX = 0, probabilityY = 0):
        self.probabilityX = ""
        self.probabilityY = ""
    def getProbability(self):
        print(self.probabilityX, self.probabilityY)
    def input(self):
        self.probabilityX = int(input("Enter probability of x:"))
        self.probabilityY = int(input("Enter probability of y:"))
        if self.probabilityX + self.probabilityY != 100:
            input(self)

def main():
    purs = Z()
    purs.input()
    purs.getProbability()
main()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Edit: Fixed typing errors

Comment: It should be `self.input()`, not `input(self)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

1. First off, these aren't class methods, that term has a specific meaning that you shouldn't confuse. You're dealing with plain methods here.
2. (obsolete) Both `input` calls are missing closing parentheses:

   ```
   self.probabilityX = int(input("Enter probability of x:")
   self.probabilityY = int(input("Enter probability of y:")
   ```

   should instead be:

   ```
   self.probabilityX = int(input("Enter probability of x:"))
   self.probabilityY = int(input("Enter probability of y:"))
   ```

   I'm guessing they are typos when you posted the question :-)
3. Calling `input(self)` doesn't do what you think. `input` is a built-in function, you're invoking that  with `self` as the prompt. You should be using `self.input()` again (and maybe renaming it to `input_probabilities` to evade confusion.
4. (obsolete) `purs.getProbabilityP` is mis-spelled, it is `purs.getProbability()`.
5. Your `__init__` doesn't make much sense:

   ```
   def __init__(self, probabilityX = 0, probabilityY = 0):
       self.probabilityX = ""
       self.probabilityY = ""
   ```

   I'm not sure why you provide default arguments for `probability(X|Y)` and then not assigning those to the corresponding instance attributes. You should do that:

   ```
   def __init__(self, probabilityX = 0, probabilityY = 0):
       self.probabilityX = probabilityX
       self.probabilityY = probabilityY
   ```

As a final point, I'd suggest not using recursion; a `while` loop does the trick effectively.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Jim!